# How to work with history with ajax in javascript?

Tags: javascript, ajax

I'm trying to find the good (and full) article about history and/or hash but to no avail. All, what I found, was about libraries, but I want to write ajax history by my hands.

All I know, that I'll use history api (that there will no number (#) sign). For users with browsers, which doesn't support history api, I'll place in `<head>` script, which will redirects like: ex.com/adress1#/adress2 to ex.com/adress2 (this is for F5).

Can you help me with it?

Comment: What have you tried so far (in addition to posting this question here)? What difficulties did you encounter?

Comment: Did you have a look at https://github.com/balupton/History.js? It supports both the history api and hashes for older browsers.

Comment: I don't want to use libraries! Did you read it? "All, what I found, was about libraries, but I want to write my ajax history by my hands."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you looking for this kind of solution?

```
$(".link").click(function() {
    window.location.hash = "param";
});
$(init);

function init() {
    ajax_page_handler();
    page_load($(window.location).attr("hash"));
}

function page_load($href) {
    if ($href != undefined && $href.substring(0, 1) == '#') {

        if ($href === "#param") {
            // load the relevant data
        }

        $('html, body').animate({
            scrollTop: 0
        }, 'slow'); // bonus
    }
}

function ajax_page_handler() {
    $(window).bind('hashchange', function() {
        $href = $(window.location).attr("hash");
        page_load($href);
    });
}​
```

Comment: No. I want a native solution without any libraries.

Comment: this is not a library for history management. i just used jQuery. if you don't need to use jQuery, you can convert to the pure JavaScript

Comment: I was searching about native solutions to write it by my hands.. But to no avail.


I have some ideas about release of this history:

#1. Bind an onclick event to all links: `<a href="/index.php" onclick="return go(this,event);">Ajax link</a>`.
this - to read `this.href` (but.. also I can read by `event.target||event.srcElement`.. dunno), event - to read, which mouse button clicked (if 3 - return true (to open in new tab), if 1 - <LOAD BY AJAX> + return false (to not go by simple link)..


#2. I wrote it: place in `<head>` script, which will redirects me on /adress2.

Comment: Well, I'm going to convert it to pure js. :)

Answer (score 0):

For older browsers, you can use this library: https://github.com/devote/HTML5-History-API it completely emulates the history in older browsers. It does not need to write an extra/unnecessary code.